# Drush alias doesn't work

Tags: drush

None of my site aliases defined in /home/peter/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php seems to work. When I ran:

```
drush sa @mysite.dk.local
```

I got

```
$aliases['mysite.dk.local'] = array (
 'uri' => 'mysite.dk',
 'root' => '/usr/share/nginx/www/drupal-7.16/sites/',
 'path-aliases' => 
 array (
   '%dump-dir' => '/usr/share/nginx/www/drupal-7.16/sites/drush.dbdumps',
   '%files' => '/usr/share/nginx/www/drupal-7.16/sites/files',
  ),
);
```

which looks ok, but when I do

```
drush @mysite.dk.local status
```

I get

```
PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini                  
Drush version         :  4.5                                    
Drush configuration   :                                         
Drush alias files     :  /home/peter/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php
```

So it seems that drush couldn't find  specified path, cause when I run second command in sites directory everything is showing up as expected. Can anybody point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your settings.php file is at /usr/share/nginx/www/drupal-7.16/sites/default/settings.php, then you should change your 'root' line as follows:

```
'root' => '/usr/share/nginx/www/drupal-7.16',
```

The way you have it, Drush is expecting that your Drupal root is at /usr/share/nginx/www/drupal-7.16/sites, which is to say that it is also expecting to find your settings.php file at /usr/share/nginx/www/drupal-7.16/sites/sites/default/settings.php. Take out the extra 'sites' as shown above, and it should work fine.